# After updating a reported property, attempting to fetch it returns the previous version, not the latest one in Azure Module Client

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Steps to reproduce:

1. Try to update any key using ModuleClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync method.
2. Get the latest twin using ModuleClient.GetTwinAsync method.
3. When you get the twin after updating then it contains the older version of reported properties.

Note: The code is working in the Local environment but when we deploy it in azure as a custom module then it stops working.

I have attached a log for reference.

```js
Twin Before Update:
{
  "deviceId": null,
  "etag": null,
  "version": null,
  "properties": {
    "desired": {
      "general": {
        "autoUpdate": false
      },
      "specific": {
        "autoUpdate": false
      },
      "$version": 1
    },
    "reported": {
      "$version": 1
    }
  }
}

Twin After Update:
{
  "deviceId": null,
  "etag": null,
  "version": null,
  "properties": {
    "desired": {
      "general": {
        "autoUpdate": false
      },
      "specific": {
        "autoUpdate": false
      },
      "$version": 1
    },
    "reported": {
      "$version": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Below code I have tried

```
public async Task UpdateReportedProperties(TwinCollection twinCollection) 
{ 

await _moduleClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(twinCollection); 

ModuleTwin = await _moduleClient!.GetTwinAsync(); 

}
```

Comment: for know we have only `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client`                                 [GetTwinAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.gettwinasync?view=azure-dotnet), [UpdateReported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.updatereportedpropertiesasync?view=azure-dotnet)/ use rest api with c#

Comment: How did you deploy custom module in azure and where did you deploy

Comment: I have deployed custom module using 
- docker build . -f Dockerfile -t
- docker push
They were deployed under my edge device as custom module.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code below interacts with Azure IoT Hub using the Azure IoT SDK. It retrieves the device twin, updates the reported properties, and then retrieves the updated twin using `UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync` and `GetTwinAsync`. The code utilizes `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client`, [GetTwinAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.gettwinasync?view=azure-dotnet), and [UpdateReported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.updatereportedpropertiesasync?view=azure-dotnet) (or) with REST API with C#.

```cs
   moduleClient = ModuleClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

   await moduleClient.OpenAsync();

   // Get the twin before update
   Twin twinBefore = await moduleClient.GetTwinAsync();
   Console.WriteLine("Twin Before Update:");
   Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(twinBefore, Formatting.Indented));

   // Update reported properties
   var patch = new
   {
       properties = new
       {
           reported = new
           {
               info = new
               {
                   origin = "Argentina",
                   version = "14.01"
               }
           }
       }
   };

   var patchJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patch);
   var patchBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(patchJson);
   var patchTwin = new TwinCollection(patchJson);

   await moduleClient.UpdateReportedPropertiesAsync(patchTwin);

   // Get the twin after update
   Twin twinAfter = await moduleClient.GetTwinAsync();
   Console.WriteLine("\nTwin After Update:");
   Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(twinAfter, Formatting.Indented));

   await moduleClient.CloseAsync();
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

The code below is a sample for connecting to Azure IoT Devices Get Twin using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/get-twin?view=rest-iothub-service-2020-03-13).

```
string deviceid = "<deviceid>";
        string hubName = "<your_iot_hub_name>";
        string APIVersion = "2020-05-31-preview";
        string URL = $"https://{hubName}.azure-devices.net/twins/{deviceid}?api-version={APIVersion}";
        string SAS_TOKEN = "<IOT_SAS_TOKEN>";
```

```
 string resultStr = string.Empty;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", SAS_TOKEN);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                resultStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Device Twin Information:");
            Console.WriteLine(resultStr);
```

Azure IoT Devices Update Twin can be done using the REST API with this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/update-twin?view=rest-iothub-service-2020-03-13).

Comment: Hi, The above code is working in the Local but when we deploy it as a custom module in azure then it stops working. I have attached the Azure log in the question itself.

Comment: checking after deploying it  to  a custom module